# Maven deploy getting the Group,Artifact,Version,Packaging parts when meven deploy failing

Tags: maven

i need to extract ( text manipulation is the last option .. )
when i execute the mvn deploy  and getting error like this :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project my-project-test: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.foo.project:my-project-test:pom:2020.1.4.my-project-test.1 from/to deployment (http://nexus/xxx/repositories/yyy/): Failed to transfer file:
```

the artifact allreay exsist in nexus , so i like to get the parts :

```
com.foo.project
my-project-test
pom
2020.1.4.my-project-test.1
```

is there any nice "maven" way to extract those parts of the artifact ? or i need to parse the return string with regexp ?

Comment: Error might have happened even when the userid, which is used to download the artifacts doesnt have access or can be the password expired. Not sure If I understand ur question on regex part. Could you please explain a bit more clearly?

Comment: i dont mind the error now ... its not the question , the question if i can get the artifact parts in nice way from maven

Comment: `Failed to transfer file: ..` the rest of the message is not there. usually failing if the GAV already exists in nexus... Can you explain what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I would suggest to prevent such errors from happening. You can e.g. write a Maven enforcer rule that checks whether the Maven coordinates were already used.

Comment: i have the error and its fine , now i like to use the data to send to error manager